# Problems with generation of dynamic code

Tags: c#, .net, reflection.emit, il

This code gif an exception: Invocation exception, please help, I don't know what happen, I think is some thing with the Add because he work when I push onto the stack intergers, and when i push lvalue It's didn't work, thanks

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain dominioAplicacion = System.Threading.Thread.GetDomain();
        AssemblyName nombre_Del_Ensamblado = new AssemblyName("ASS");
        AssemblyBuilder ensambladoBld = dominioAplicacion.DefineDynamicAssembly(nombre_Del_Ensamblado, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
        ModuleBuilder moduloBld = ensambladoBld.DefineDynamicModule("<MOD");
        TypeBuilder claseContenedoraBld = moduloBld.DefineType("claseContenedora");
        MethodBuilder mainBld = claseContenedoraBld.DefineMethod("main", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static, typeof(void), Type.EmptyTypes);
        ILGenerator il = mainBld.GetILGenerator();

        FieldBuilder campoBld = claseContenedoraBld.DefineField("x", typeof(int), FieldAttributes.Public | FieldAttributes.Static);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 2);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stsfld, campoBld);

        FieldBuilder campoBld1 = claseContenedoraBld.DefineField("x1", typeof(int), FieldAttributes.Public | FieldAttributes.Static);

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 2);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stsfld, campoBld1);

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldftn, campoBld);
      //il.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox, typeof(int));
      //il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);


        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldftn, campoBld1);
        //il.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox, typeof(int));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
        //il.Emit(OpCodes.Box, typeof(int));
        //il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldftn, campoBld1);
        //il.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox, typeof(int));

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Add);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);
        //il.Emit(OpCodes.Stsfld, campoBld1);




        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);


        Type t = claseContenedoraBld.CreateType();

        object ptInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(t, new Type[] { });

        t.InvokeMember("main", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public,
            null,
            ptInstance,
            new object[0]);

        var x = t.GetField("x");

    }
```

Comment: Please post the exception text.

Comment: What should be the complete IL code? Would that IL code work if it were in an assembly? I would start looking for an error there

Answer (score 3):

Your IL is simply invalid.  The exception isn't great but you're tinkering in the bowels of the JIT compiler.  Opcodes.Ldsftn does *not* do what you think it does, you'll need Ldsfld to load a field.  I can't really figure out what code you're trying to write but this ought to be close.  It doesn't crash anyway:

```
        FieldBuilder campoBld = claseContenedoraBld.DefineField("x", typeof(int), FieldAttributes.Public | FieldAttributes.Static);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 2);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stsfld, campoBld);
        FieldBuilder campoBld1 = claseContenedoraBld.DefineField("x1", typeof(int), FieldAttributes.Public | FieldAttributes.Static);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 2);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stsfld, campoBld1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld, campoBld);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld, campoBld1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Add);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

The best way to figure out what IL to use is to write your code in C# first, then disassemble it with Ildasm.exe to see what the IL looks like.

Comment: @cary, sounds like a solution.  Please close your thread by marking it answered.